# Wrap stacked cards in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to stack some playing cards like the image shows. BUT I want the cards to wrap into a new line when there is no more space on the device.

[image: Deck of cards]

This is what I have so far

```dart
class CollectionOfCards extends StatelessWidget {
  List<PlayingCard> cards;

  CollectionOfCards(this.cards);
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Stack(
      children: [
        ...cards
            .asMap()
            .map(
              (key, value) => MapEntry(
                key,
                Positioned(
                  child: PlayingCardWidget(value),
                  left: 35.0 * key,
                ),
              ),
            )
            .values
            .toList(),
      ],
      overflow: Overflow.visible,
    );
  }
}
```

Any ideas how to do this? I imagine it is somewhat a common task.

Another idea would be to make a fan of cards that can always fit but I imagine thats harder to achieve!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assume we want to have 2 rows of cards, each containing 10 cards. We need to use `Positioned` in a way that every card is positioned according to its index in the row(from 0 to 9) and its column(column 0 or column 1). So we need to set `top` and `left` in the `Positioned` widget. The `0.7 * cardHeight` in `top` is for the vertical stacking, you can change that to `cardHeight` if you don't want to have vertical stacking.

**Note**: Set width and height of the cards using `MediaQuery` size. I didn't have the cards so I just made empty containers instead.

```
class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  List<Widget> _cards = [];
  void _initCards() {
    double cardHeight = 400 / 2;
    double cardWidth = 2500 / 20;
    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
      _cards.add(Positioned(
        left: ((i >= 10) ?  i - 10 : i) * cardWidth / 2,
        top: (i >= 10) ? 0.7 * cardHeight : 0,
        child: Card(
          elevation: 10,
          color: Colors.white,
          shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10)),
          child: Container(width: cardWidth, height: cardHeight),
        ),
      ));
    }
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _initCards();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        body: Container(
          padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 15.0),
          child: Stack(
              children: _cards
          ),
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            color: Colors.yellow,
          ),
        ),
    );
  }
}
```

Result:
[image: result]

Comment: Thanks. I've implemented something like this. Instead of hardcoding the number of cards per row I'm using this `final int cardsPerRow = (widgetWidth / cardWith / stackSkew - 1 / stackSkew).floor()` (non trivial but should be right according to my math). In your example stackSkew is 0.7 and widgetWidth is the width of the row.

Answer (score 2):

Just for reference. I ended up with solution like this inspired by @Mobina's answer

```dart
class CollectionOfCards extends StatelessWidget {
  final List<PlayingCard> cards;
  final double stackSkew = 0.4;

  CollectionOfCards(this.cards);
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final double widgetWidth = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width - 16;
    final double cardWith = PlayingCardWidget.defaultWidth(context);
    final int cardsPerRow =
        (widgetWidth / cardWith / stackSkew - 1 / stackSkew).floor();
    return Stack(
      children: [
        ...cards
            .asMap()
            .map(
              (index, card) {
                return MapEntry(
                  index,
                  Positioned(
                    child: Draggable(
                      childWhenDragging: Container(),
                      feedback: PlayingCardWidget(card: card),
                      child: PlayingCardWidget(
                        card: card,
                      ),
                    ),
                    left: stackSkew *
                        cardWith *
                        (index - (cardsPerRow) * (index / cardsPerRow).floor()),
                    top: (card.heightFromWidth(cardWith) + 2) *
                        (index / cardsPerRow).floor(),
                  ),
                );
              },
            )
            .values
            .toList(),
      ],
      overflow: Overflow.visible,
    );
  }
}
```

It seems to work flawless.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

One way you can do this is by passing `left` as well as `top` parameter to `Positioned` calculated based on -

- Screen width
- Card index  (*"key"* in your code)
- Card width
- Card height

See the demo on dartpad - https://dartpad.dev/d36e018c1f1c7a6cd4b91d5b09e69a7c

Answer (score 0):

Try using Wrap() widget inside a Column()

```
Column(
  children: <Widget>[
    Wrap(
     children: <Widget>[
        //your card widget
      ]
    )
  ]
)
```

Comment: I'll lose the stacking (overlapping cards) if I don't use Stack with position. I could just replace Stack with Wrap and then I get what I want but without overlapping cards